# Rolling Mean not being calculated on a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an issue on calculating the rolling mean for a column I added in the code. For some reason, it doesnt work on the column I added but works on a column from the original csv.

Original dataframe from the csv as follow:

```
        Open    High     Low    Last  Change   Volume  Open Int
 Time                                                               
09/20/19   98.50   99.00   98.35   98.95    0.60   3305.0       0.0
09/19/19  100.35  100.75   98.10   98.35   -2.00  17599.0       0.0
09/18/19  100.65  101.90  100.10  100.35    0.00  18258.0  121267.0
09/17/19  103.75  104.00  100.00  100.35   -3.95  34025.0  122453.0
09/16/19  102.30  104.95  101.60  104.30    1.55  21403.0  127447.0

Ticker = pd.read_csv('\\......\Historical data\kcz19 daily.csv', 
index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
Ticker['Return'] = np.log(Ticker['Last'] / Ticker['Last'].shift(1)).fillna('')
Ticker['ret20'] = Ticker['Return'].rolling(window=20, win_type='triang').mean()

print(Ticker.head())

           Open    High     Low  ...  Open Int      Return       ret20
Time                              ...                                  
09/20/19   98.50   99.00   98.35  ...       0.0                        
09/19/19  100.35  100.75   98.10  ...       0.0 -0.00608213 -0.00608213
09/18/19  100.65  101.90  100.10  ...  121267.0   0.0201315   0.0201315
09/17/19  103.75  104.00  100.00  ...  122453.0           0           0
09/16/19  102.30  104.95  101.60  ...  127447.0   0.0386073   0.0386073
```

ret20 column should have the rolling mean of the column Return so it should show some data starting from raw 21 whereas it is only a copy of column Return here.
If I replace with the Last column it will work.
Below is the result using colum Last

```
           Open    High     Low  ...  Open Int      Return     ret20
Time                              ...                                
09/20/19   98.50   99.00   98.35  ...       0.0                   NaN
09/19/19  100.35  100.75   98.10  ...       0.0 -0.00608213       NaN
09/18/19  100.65  101.90  100.10  ...  121267.0   0.0201315       NaN
09/17/19  103.75  104.00  100.00  ...  122453.0           0       NaN
09/16/19  102.30  104.95  101.60  ...  127447.0   0.0386073       NaN
09/13/19  103.25  103.60  102.05  ...  128707.0  -0.0149725       NaN
09/12/19  102.80  103.85  101.15  ...  128904.0  0.00823848       NaN
09/11/19  102.00  104.70  101.40  ...  132067.0 -0.00193237       NaN
09/10/19   98.50  102.25   98.00  ...  135349.0  -0.0175614       NaN
09/09/19   97.00   99.25   95.30  ...  137347.0  -0.0335283       NaN
09/06/19   95.35   97.30   95.00  ...  135399.0  -0.0122889       NaN
09/05/19   96.80   97.45   95.05  ...  136142.0  -0.0171477       NaN
09/04/19   95.65   96.95   95.50  ...  134864.0   0.0125002       NaN
09/03/19   96.00   96.60   94.20  ...  134685.0  -0.0109291       NaN
08/30/19   95.40   97.20   95.10  ...  134061.0   0.0135137       NaN
08/29/19   97.05   97.50   94.75  ...  132639.0  -0.0166584       NaN
08/28/19   97.40   98.15   95.95  ...  130573.0   0.0238601       NaN
08/27/19   97.35   98.00   96.40  ...  129921.0 -0.00410889       NaN
08/26/19   95.55   98.50   95.25  ...  129003.0   0.0035962       NaN
08/23/19   96.90   97.40   95.05  ...  130268.0  -0.0149835  98.97775
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Can you share what doesn't work with the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `.fillna('')` is creating a string in the first row which then creates errors for the rolling calculation in `Ticker['ret20']`.

Delete this and the code will run fine:
`Ticker['Return'] = np.log(Ticker['Last'] / Ticker['Last'].shift(1))`